# assembly retn , jmp , process register

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers, eip

I started C++ programming recently alongside with assembly language.  I would like to clarify a few things.

From what I read, the instruction pointer gets the address where it should execute next from the `retn` instruction. Wont it be the same as doing a `jmp` because `jmp` also sets the instruction pointer?

If I am right, what's the difference between `retn` and `jmp`? If I'm wrong, can someone explain with C pseudo code?

What is the assembly equivalent for an infinite loop?

I read that `EAX,EBX,ECX,EDX` are interchangeable but do they have any difference? If so,in which scenario should I specifically use `EAX/EBX/ECX/EDX`.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be talking about subroutine calls, so here's the lowdown on that.

When you *call* a subroutine, it looks something like this (the addresses will be different but I didn't want to confuse you with variable-length instructions):

```
1234  call 8888
1235  <next instruction>
```

What happens is that the `call` first places the next instruction pointer `1235` onto the stack (a last-in-first-out data structure), then sets the instruction pointer to whatever you're calling, `8888` in this case.

Later on, a return is done at `8889`:

```
8888  mov eax, 0
8889  ret
```

What the return does is simply pop the first value off the stack (ie, `1235`, which was pushed by the call) and loads it into the instruction pointer. So it's not the *return* telling you where to go, it's the information that was pushed on the stack by the *call.*

If you had a `jmp` instruction at the end of your subroutine, it would only be able to return to one point in the code (discounting all the wonderful things you could do with other addressing modes for now):

```
8889  jmp 1235
```

By using return, you return to wherever you came from, no matter where that was.

---

The assembler for an infinite loop can be as simple as:

```
loopy:
    jmp loopy
```

---

As for the registers, `eax`, `ebx`, `ecx` and `edx` are considered the general purpose registers. This distinguishes them from the more special purpose registers like the stack pointer, base pointer, source and destination indexes and so on, which have specialised instructions depending on their use.

`ax` may have had some extra powers in very early iterations of the x86 architecture but I'm not sure that's still the case. If you're coding up your own stuff, you should be able to mostly use them interchangeably. If you're following an API or ABI, you'll need to follow the rules that it imposes (such as the Linux system call interface where `eax` holds the system call number).

Answer (score 1):

The difference of `ret` and `jmp` in terms of a C/C++ function is similar to this:

```
int foo()
{
   int x = 3+4;

   if(x < 10)
      goto Quit;    <- similar to jmp

   x += 10;

 Quit:
   return x;     <- similar to ret
```

}

When you do `return` in C it's a bit more complicated what really happens on the machine level, because additional code is often executed, for example put the return value in `eax` and  cleaning up the stack.ö In C++ local objects will get desctructed as well, but the ultiate and of the function will be a `ret` instruction.

> What is the assembly equivalent for an infinite loop ?

```
while(1);
```

is like

```
000000 jmp 000000
```

or more advanced

```
00000  inc ecx
00001  jmp 00000
```

General purpose registers. In some cases you can intermix the registers and use them however you want. For some instructions, they expect to be using specific registers. You must look up the instruction manual to see where this is the case.

One example is the `movsw`, which requires you to use `(E)SI` and `(E)DI`, so in this case you are not free to choose. If you use `rep movsw` additional `(E)CX` is also used.
Typically the assembler knows which registers are valid for an inxtruction and will give you an error message, but of course, you should look up the manual to be sure, because you might get unexpected results if the assembler can not throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

`eax` and `edx` are implicit operands in division and int the wide-result versions of multiplication. There are also special sign-extending instructions that operate on only parts of `rax` (opcode 98) or that sign-extend `eax` into `edx:eax` (opcode 99). Decimal math instructions all work on parts of `eax`.

`ecx` (well `cl` really but close enough) is the only register that you could shift by before Haswell (which introduces `sarx`, `shlx` and `shrx` all of which can shift by any GPR). `ecx` is also used as the counter by rep-prefixes. `pcmp*stri` puts the length in `ecx`.

Many special-purpose instructions have no explicit operands but instead assign special meaning to certain GPR's, for example `cpuid`, `rdpmc`, `rdtsc`, `wrmsr`, `xgetbv`, `xsave`. Usually `edx:eax`, often `ecx` as well, and very rarely `ebx`. You probably won't have to deal with these a lot.